# making provision of an eip optional in a terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, conditional-statements, parameter-passing, terraform

I have a module I use to create all my aws ec2 instances, which works fine. I now want to, optionally, be able to associate the instance with an Elastic IP address. The associate part works fine, it is the **optional** bit I'm struggling with. I'm using terraform 13.5, so I've tried playing around with for_each, but it doesn't seem to be the answer.

So the question is, how can I make the creation of the `aws_eip_assoication` resource optional in the module below. So the same module can be used for all ec2 instances, whether public, private, etc.?

```
# module/ec2/main.tf
resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  
  subnet_id = var.subnet_id
  ami = var.ami
  key_name = var.key_name
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.vpc_security_group_ids
  
  # Optional parameters that the caller may specify
  associate_public_ip_address = var.associate_public_ip_address
  iam_instance_profile = var.iam_instance_profile
  private_ip = var.private_ip  
}

#
# ??? How do I make this resource optional? So it only applies to ec2 instances
# that have passed in details of the eip via var.public_eip?
#
resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  instance_id   = aws_instance.server.id
  allocation_id = var.public_eip
}
```

```
# module/ec2/variables.tf

# Mandatory Parameters
variable "subnet_id" {}
variable "ami" {}
variable "instance_type" {}
variable "vpc_security_group_ids" {}

variable private_ip {
    description = "A pre-assigned private IP address"
    default = ""
} 
# Don't assign a public IP address by default
variable "associate_public_ip_address" {
    default = false
}
variable public_eip {
    description = "A pre-assigned public (elastic) (eip) IP address"
    default = null
}
```

The calling code, itself a module.

```
module "bastion_server" { 
    source = "../module/ec2"
    subnet_id                   = module.public_subnets.output_subnet_ids[0]
    ami                         = var.pattern_config.public_subnets.bastion.ami
    instance_type               = var.pattern_config.public_subnets.bastion.instance_type
    vpc_security_group_ids      = [module.bastion_sg.this_security_group_id]
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    public_eip                  = "eipalloc-0d4edc8bxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genneraly for conditional resources you would use [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/meta-arguments/count.html) with [conditional expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/conditionals.html).

Therefore, in your case, the following should be enough:

```
resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {

  count = var.public_eip == null ? 0 : 1

  instance_id   = aws_instance.server.id
  allocation_id = var.public_eip
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Went off on a wild goose chase with for_each on this one. `count` is much simpler.